# Bypassing the multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, coffeescript

I need to get some data from complex array into array.
For example I have this structure:

```
animals =
     /*...*/
         list: [
           {
             type: "fluffy"
             withCategories: false
             animal: [
               {
                 name: "Patrik"
                 description: "..."
                 price: 135
                 weight: 220
                 rating: 94
               }
               {
                 name: "Mike"
                 description: "..."
                 price: 135
                 weight: 235
                 rating: 97
               }
             ]
           }
           {
             imageUrl: "/img/borsh.jpg"
             type: "pets"
             withCategories: true
             categories: [
               {
                 name: "parrot"
                 imageUrl: "/img/parrot.jpg"
                 withCategories: false
                 animal: [
                   {
                     name: "Kesha"
                     description: "..."
                     price: 75
                     weight: 250
                     rating: 89
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
```

As a result I need one array with elements of animal:
*//result = [object1 -> name: Patrik, price: 135 ..], ..., [object3 -> name: Kesha, description: ...]*
As you can see on the lower level we go down recursively if the parameter "withCategories" = true.
I've tried to realize it:

```
PlacesService.getAllAnimals = ->
    merged = []
    temp = (getAnimalByCategory(category) for category in animals.list)
    merged = merged.concat.apply(merged, temp)
    return merged

  getAnimalByCategory = (category) ->
    if category.withCategories == false
      return category.animal
    else
      (getAnimalByCategory(an) for an in category.categories)
```

But something wrong:( Could somebody help me please? I can't find any mistakes.

Comment: Also we can have unlimited number of nested levels, but only lower level has the parameter "withCategories" = false.

Comment: Maybe you can find your mistakes by describing *what* is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect your `getAnimalByCategory` to return a flat list, so that the results of a loop can be merged by a `concat`. However, you don't return such in the recursive case.

```
PlacesService.getAllAnimals = ->
  [].concat.apply([], getAnimalByCategory(category) for category in animals.list)

getAnimalByCategory = (category) ->
  if not category.withCategories
    category.animal
  else
    [].concat.apply([], getAnimalByCategory(an) for an in category.categories)
```